# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Having following code:
https://github.com/arturmkr/myReportProblem

Using Java 11.

When I try to execute it I am having issue:

```
./gradlew clean ui:test 

> Task :ui:test FAILED

com.db.demo.ui.DummyCheck > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:581

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

Who could help?

Comment: There's no DummyCheck class at the link you provided. There's only a UiApplication class. Are you sure you provide the correct link?

Comment: @OnurBaştürk, Yes, it's in the test directory.

path:
/ui/src/test/java/com/db/demo/ui/DummyCheck.java

Comment: Ok you're right. Check out https://mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/ and https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571 while i'm trying your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now it works (but your tests fail):

1. Add to your non-Spring boot project's build.gradle (I mean your repository project's build.gradle)

```
    bootJar 
    {
        enabled = false
    }

    jar 
    {
        enabled = true
    }
```

2. `./gradlew clean build`

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: Well I downloaded your code and opened it in Intellij IDEA. Then added this part to the build.gradle and it worked. Check out your project in a clean directory and try again. May be it helps. Is it the same error again? Any other logs?

Answer (score 0):

I just removed from `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
jar { enabled = false }
```

And it helped